# Reinstall Windows: OS on SSD, programs on HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I want to reinstall Windows on my PC. At the moment only the OS is installed on my SSD. Most programs and data are on my HDD.

Is there a way to reinstall Windows without reinstall ing all programs? Can I export and later import the registry entries?

// Edit:
I am currently using Windows 10 n but want to switch to a fresh Windows 10 (not n version)

Comment: I was interessted whether there is a general way to do this, but I edited some information in for you.

Comment: It is possible, but you would need to gather a lot of information (what program stores what settings where? And this is not only registry, but also spread across several folders on your drive - one of the few things that Linux does better). You'll easily spend 1-2 weeks for this. It's much easier and way less time consuming to just reinstall everything.